# Why there is huge difference between PSI score of mobile and desktop sites?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I want to know why there is a big difference between PSI scores of mobile site and desktop site

Answer (score 1):

Google Page Speed Insights uses different parameters for desktop vs mobile testing.

**For desktop** the connection speed used is not throttled, it will load as fast as a **web browser** will allow (i.e. limited by round trip times, maximum simultaneous downloads per domain and CPU processing power of a decent PC).

**For mobile** however Google tries to simulate a real world example of a mobile phone on a 4G connection.

4 x CPU slowdown as mobile phones are less powerful and network throttling that includes slow upload and downloads and **more importantly** simulates a high Round Trip Time for each resource request (higher latency).