# Page Speed Insights and Measure Versus GT Metrix different results

Tags: performance, pagespeed-insights, gtmetrix

My agency is showing our performance as great in GT Metrix. In page speed insights[GTmetrix web vitals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0THFG.png) and measure, [pagespeedinsightsresults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mrcv.png)I am seeing a different picture. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GT Metrix looks at your page on desktop without any throttling applied.

Page Speed Insights applies throttling to the network (to simulate 4G) and to the CPU (to simulate a mid-tier mobile phone with less processing power) and in a mobile viewport.

Also on Page Speed Insights the "Origin Summary" is **real world data** from people's devices, so that is the more reliable and important information.

See these answers I have given for more info:

- [throttling applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866249/what-network-conditions-are-pagespeed-insights-using-for-desktop-and-mobile-prof/59866425#59866425)
- [difference between mobile and desktop scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590778/why-there-is-huge-difference-between-psi-score-of-mobile-and-desktop-sites/57864278#57864278)